# How to open MSWord document in our Android App

Tags: android, android-widget

I am working on an Android Application where I need to open an MS_Word foramt file.How can this be possible in android? The context is the file should be viewed in the same way as if we view msword document in desktop.can anyone help me in sorting out this issue?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: @bzlm this is a badly asked but perfectly valid software development question and therefore not a question that should be on android.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Janusz Sorry, I read its charter a bit too quickly. :)

Comment: Janusz, did u mean this can't be done in Android programming. That is displaying an msword document stored in res folder or any other folder of Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can this be possible in android?

Step #1: Find an application that views MS Word documents.

Step #2: Ask the developers of that application if and how to integrate with theirs.

Comment: And if you're deadset on doing this on your own, you'll need to know the format of an MS Word file, and then parse it bit by bit.  Since I'm pretty sure the MS Word format isn't openly available, and this would be a ton of work if it were, CommonsWare's answer is your best best.